# How to make simple script dynamic?

Tags: jquery, image, dynamic, slider

I'm trying to make a panorama image slide continually left and right and I've achieved that, but I need help making the script dynamic and update `MyWidth` on the fly when the window gets resized (or when you change mobile device's orientation) because otherwise the image doesn't move all the way to the edge.

My panorama image is fitted to the height of the window:

```
<section class="full-height" style="width: 100%; position: relative; overflow: hidden;">

<img src="images/panorama.jpg" id="panorama" class="full-height" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" />

</section>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var $window = $(window);
var windowWidth = $window.width();

var b = function($b,speed){
beeWidth = $b.width();
var MyWidth = beeWidth - windowWidth;

$b.animate({ //animates the bee to the right side of the screen
"left": -MyWidth
}, speed, function(){ //when finished it goes back to the left side
$b.animate({
    "left": 0 + "px"
}, speed, function(){
         b($b, speed) //finally it recalls the same function and everything starts again
    });
});

};

$(function(){
b($("#panorama"), 50000);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I wonder if an image, or a JS Fiddle, would be useful here, to demonstrate the problem? It sounds like you need to trap the resize event in the browser, and send new dimensions to the animation system.

Comment: I have removed a secondary question, since I think that is best dealt with separately. Ask another question about that please (possibly after this is resolved, in case answers suggest an implementation change that would render any animation smoothing work redundant).